# Is there a way to get the count of every element in lists stored as rows in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby, dtype

**Hi, I'm using pandas to display and analyze a csv file, some columns were 'object dtype' and were displayed as lists, I used 'literal_eval' to convert the rows of a column named 'sdgs' to lists, my problem is how to use 'groupby' or any another way to display the count of every element stored at this lists uniquely, especially since there are many common elements between these lists.**

```
df = pd.read_csv("../input/covid19-public-media-dataset/covid19_articles_20220420.csv")
df.dropna(subset=['sdgs'],inplace=True)
df=df[df.astype(str)['sdgs'] != '[]']
df.sdgs = df.sdgs.apply(literal_eval)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

[This is a sample of data and my problem is about the last column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgwDl.jpg)

[This is an example of the elements I want to count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhXrN.jpg)

**Thank you**

Comment: It's not clear what you need. You just want the count of words in the `sdgs` column inside the overall dataframe? Please post some example input and desired output

Comment: Sorry, I edited and attached a picture displaying examples, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this example data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'domain': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
                   'sdgs': [['Just', 'a', 'sentence'], ['another', 'sentence'], 
                            ['a', 'word', 'and', 'a', 'word'], ['nothing', 'here']]})
print(df)
```

```
  domain                     sdgs
0      a      [Just, a, sentence]
1      a      [another, sentence]
2      b  [a, word, and, a, word]
3      c          [nothing, here]
```

To get the word count across all the lists in the `sdgs` column you can concatenate the lists with [`Series.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) and use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

word_counts = collections.Counter(df['sdgs'].agg(sum))
print(word_counts)
```

```
Counter({'a': 3, 'sentence': 2, 'word': 2, 'Just': 1, 'another': 1, 
         'and': 1, 'nothing': 1, 'here': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on the lists like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'domain': ['a', 'b'], 'sdgs': ["['AaaBbbAndCcc','DddAndEee']","['BbbCccAndDdd']"]})
df
#   domain                          sdgs
# 0      a  ['AaaBbbAndCcc','DddAndEee']
# 1      b              ['BbbCccAndDdd']

# turn lists into strings, split at capitalized names
df['sdgs']=df.sdgs.apply(lambda x: re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", ''.join(literal_eval(x))).split())
df
#   domain                                 sdgs
# 0      a  [Aaa, Bbb, And, Ccc, Ddd, And, Eee]
# 1      b                 [Bbb, Ccc, And, Ddd]

df.explode('sdgs')
#   domain sdgs
# 0      a  Aaa
# 0      a  Bbb
# 0      a  And
# 0      a  Ccc
# 0      a  Ddd
# 0      a  And
# 0      a  Eee
# 1      b  Bbb
# 1      b  Ccc
# 1      b  And
# 1      b  Ddd
```

Now you can group for instance like this:

```
df.explode('sdgs').groupby(['domain']).count()
#         sdgs
# domain      
# a          7
# b          4
```

EDIT: you'll need some other way to split the strings, also it might be necessary to remove duplicate values